# Is GameKit a viable option for device to device communication without server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I apologise for the broad question.

I want to have two devices communicate with each other, from background, sending their location, a bit like a bad "Find my friends" copy. I have basic knowledge on Core Location services, what I need is a way to send location data from one device to the other.

Is GameKit communication fit for this purpose? Is it possible to invoke a device-device connection from background and send data with this framework?

Alternatively, is there any other better way to do this.